# For a subheading, can I replace "Obligation to Implement the Security and Maintenance" with "Security, Maintenance and Obligation"?

Tags: phrase-choice

For a subheading, can I replace "Obligation to Implement the Security and Maintenance" with "Security, Maintenance and Obligation"? The former might be too long for a subheading of a document.

Comment: Maintenance and security obligations?

Comment: What about Security and Maintenance Obligation?

Comment: That works fine too, IMHO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might have been helpful to know the heading too.

A possible subheading could be:

> Obligations: Security and Maintenance

---

As discussed in the comments, the following might be acceptable too:

> Maintenance and Security Obligations